# How can I make a picture a user uploaded to automatically adjust to a specific width and height on my PHP website without spoiling the dimentions?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have created a website on which a user can upload pictures, but I did not specify the picture dimensions they can upload. So, how can I make a picture uploaded by the user to automatically adjust to a specific width and height in the database before it can be fetched to be displayed on my site?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

I imagine You can use a function like this:

```
function resize_my_image_to_max_900($my_image){
    $control_width = imagesx($my_image);     // Store original width value
    $control_height = imagesy($my_image);     // Store original height value
    $n_width = $control_width;            // Default, case value <= 900
    $n_height = $control_height;           // Default, case value <= 900

    if($n_width >= 900 || $n_height >= 900):
        while(($n_width >= 900) || ($n_height >= 900)):
            $n_width = $control_width - ($control_width * 0.25);
            $n_height = $control_height - ($control_height * 0.25);
            
            if($n_width < 900 || $n_height < 900): break; endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width, $n_height);

    imagealphablending($new_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $my_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $n_width, $n_height, $control_width, $control_height);
}
```

Have a nice day and good work.